# Pandas - Cumsum over time periods + groupby time

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I currently have a dataframe that looks like:

[image]

I am trying to figure out how to do the following, and just don't know how to start....

1. For each DAY, cumsum the volume..
2. After this, group the data by time
   of day (ie, 10min intervals). If a day doesn't have that interval
   (sometimes gaps), then it should just be treated as 0.

Any help would really be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For number 1:

Let's use `resample` with `D`:

```
df.resample('D')['volume'].cumsum()
```

For Number 2:

Let's use `resample('10T')` with `asfreq` and `replace`:

```
df.resample('10T').asfreq().replace(np.nan,0)
```

Comment: I'm going through this right now. Will mark when finished.

Comment: Yeah, def.  I thought there was a mistake, but realized that I'm going to have to merge a bunch of dataframes first, then sum them. Thanks again

Comment: Hello, I am looking at a problem like this, Can you help me with this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57735722/how-to-do-cumsum-based-on-a-time-condition-resample-pandas