# How to do cumsum based on a time condition - resample pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby, python-datetime

I have a dataframe like as shown below

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
   'subject_id':[1,1,1,1,1,1],
   'time_1' :['2173-04-03 10:00:00','2173-04-03 10:15:00','2173-04-03 
              10:30:00','2173-04-03 10:45:00','2173-04-03 11:05:00','2173- 
              04-03 11:15:00'],
   'val' :[5,6,5,6,6,6]
})
```

I would like to find the total duration of a value appearing in sequence. Below example will help you understand

[image]

From the above screenshot, you can see that `6` occurs in sequence from `10:45` to `23:59` whereas other values (it could be any values in real time though) are not in sequence at all.

I did something like this **but doesn't give expected output**. It cumsums all values

```
df['time_1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time_1'])
df['seq'] = df['val'] == df['val'].shift(-1)

s=pd.to_timedelta(24,unit='h')-(df.time_1-df.time_1.dt.normalize())
df['tdiff'] =df.groupby(df.time_1.dt.date).time_1.diff().shift(-1).fillna(s).dt.total_seconds()/3600
df.groupby([df['seq'] == True])['tdiff'].cumsum() # do cumulative sum only when the values are in sequence
```

How can I do cumulative sum to a group based on a condition?

I expect my output to be like as shown below. You see `13:15` because we don't see any other value in our data for next `13:15` hour from first occurrence of `6` which is at `10:45` (`24:00 hr - 10:45` gives `13:15`)

[image]

**Test dataframe**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
     'subject_id':[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
     'time_1' :['2173-04-03 12:35:00','2173-04-03 12:50:00','2173-04-03 
     12:59:00','2173-04-03 13:14:00','2173-04-03 13:37:00','2173-04-04 
     11:30:00','2173-04-05 16:00:00','2173-04-05 22:00:00','2173-04-06 
     04:00:00','2173-04-06 04:30:00','2173-04-06 08:00:00'],
     'val' :[5,5,5,5,10,5,5,8,3,4,6]
   })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, Try with :

```
m=df.groupby(df.val.ne(df.val.shift()).cumsum()).first().rename_axis(None)
c=pd.to_timedelta(24,unit='h')-(m.time_1-m.time_1.dt.normalize())
final=m.assign(cumsum=m.time_1.diff().shift(-1).fillna(c))
```

---

```
   subject_id              time_1  val   cumsum
1           1 2173-04-03 10:00:00    5 00:15:00
2           1 2173-04-03 10:15:00    6 00:15:00
3           1 2173-04-03 10:30:00    5 00:15:00
4           1 2173-04-03 10:45:00    6 13:15:00
```

**Details**:

`df.val.ne(df.val.shift()).cumsum()` evaluates if values changes every row , and groups same values into a single group.

Based on this group we groupby and get first entry of each group. Then we find `diff()` from `time_1` and shift 1 place above to align to the top index. fillna with difference from 24 hrs.

Comment: Hi, One question with this. If the values are same for next day, then I guess this considers as part of same sequence. How to restrict the sequence only within that day? I used this condition but I don't seem to get it right?  `(df.date.eq(df.date.shift()) & df.val.ne(df.val.shift())).cumsum()`

Comment: I have given a sample dataframe in updated post at the bottom. It doesn't seem to be treating them as values from different days.

Comment: Just to help you understand, `2173-04-04 11:30:00  5` and `2173-04-05 16:00:00 5` are being treated same sequence. In the end it ignores the value `2173-04-05 16:00:00 5`. Hence I added `date` in sequence check. Am I missing anything?

Comment: I have converted the `time_1` as `date` to have the date component. If I have `time_1` it might consider `hms` as well and will not allow us to group for cumulative values. So ignored that.

Comment: In addition, I tried this `date` and `val` condition with different operators `&` and `|` but it doesn't help me get the required output. just an update on what I tried. Seems something simple has to be done but i am missing it.

Comment: @SSMK try setting `m` in my answer as `df.assign(date=df.time_1.dt.date).groupby(['date',df.val.ne(df.val.shift()).cumsum()]).first().reset_index(drop=True)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198771/discussion-between-anky-91-and-ssmk).

Answer (score 1):

1) first you should convert to datetime your column time:

```
df.time_1 = pd.to_datetime(df.time_1)
```

2) then you can group by consecutive repetitive values:

```
df['val_groups'] = (df.val != df.val.shift()).cumsum()
```

3) also, you need for each group the time till next value:

```
df['time_till_next_val'] = df.time_1.diff().shift(-1)
```

4) next will be to group by the consecutive value groups and calculate your `consum` column:

```
 cols = ['subject_id', 'time_1', 'val', 'consum']
 df_consum = df.groupby(['subject_id', 'val', 'val_groups']).agg(consum=('time_till_next_val', 'sum'), time_1=('time_1', 'first')).reset_index()[cols]
```

5) calculate for the last group the `consum` value

```
last_start_time_group = df.time_1.iloc[df.val_groups.eq(df.val_groups.max()).idxmax()]
last_start_time_group = pd.to_timedelta(last_start_time_group.strftime('%H:%M:%S'), unit='d')
last_group_consum = pd.Timedelta(hours=24) - last_start_time_group

df_consum.consum.iloc[-1] = last_group_consum
df_consum
```

output:

[image]

Comment: just added the last step to calculate last group `consum`